# litmus grunt returning "could't authenticate you"

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using `grunt-litmus` and I'm adding my username + password but when i run my task I get a:

`Could't authenticate you` - They have the typo.

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you. I think the litmus.com address might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your account information is incorrect. If you go to your Litmus profile, there is a place that says `Subdomain for API`. This is what you put in the URL:

`https://[subdomain API].litmus.com`

When running the grunt command, it will create a new version under the same name so long as you keep it consistent. I believe it uses the `<title>` tag to determine what to call it.